# How to debug unmanaged dll in Visual studio, when we dont have source for that dll?

Tags: c#, dll, com, visual-studio-debugging

In my application i am using the third party dll and i dont have any soruce code avialable.
Now i am getting the exception in Windows7 OS, so i would like to debug and kwow what is the exact reason.

Reflector will not help me in this case as its a unmanaged dll. And decompiler is giving error on passing this dll(Extraction of source code).

To debug in visual studio, it expects the PDB file and .pdb can be generated only from source code.

In the debug section i slected "Enable Native code debugging option" and in security section i selected the option as paritially trusted application to get rid of the exception.

I am not able to conclude, what could be the problem and dont have any idea apart from above, how to resolve?

On my knowlege we can not debug unmanaged dll, if we dont have source code available.

Can any one please suggest, if we have any techniques around that.

My thought process: If i can get runtime information on which API its failing, i could opt for alternative API and resolve the problem.

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Siva.

Comment: You can't debug without debug symbols. Unless you undestand disassembler. Who did you get the dll from? They might be able to help. Do you get similar errors if you stub the 3rd party stuff - are you sure it's not your code?

Comment: One can debug native code without source in VS just fine. It requires some level of assembly knowledge, but it should not be a problem... (at least not one that can be solved on SO).

Comment: @doctorlove: yes, its a thridparty dll and soruce code is properitery one for them and i can not ask them for source code. Till now we were using this dll in windows XP where it is working fine. Now we started testing in Windows7 started crashing. So with you all suggession i can report the problem to the third party and ask to them to resolve.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: I am getting an excpetion with this dll. so my intenstion is lets not depend upon that dll and write my own code in .Net. But the out come should be same. If i can debug the dll inside, i can get the techniues used, so i can write in similar lines. And i agree with you that we can still have a chance with assembly code.

Comment: Reporting to creators of the library is your safest choice. Note that there is very thin line between debugging and reverse engineering - it may be good idea to consult lawyer before attempting to  "get the techniues used, so i can write in similar lines".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you can debug it. You can step through assembly code just fine and check the state of registers, etc.

It seems that you really want to debug by inspecting and executing the original source code. This is obviously impossible without the source code, as it is in general not possible to reverse engineer the source code from optimized native executable (it is possible to reverse engineer functionally equivalent code, but this can differ heavily from the original source). Native dll usually doesn't contain names of the symbols (classes, functions, members, etc) except for the exported ones, so it is not possible to create e.g. a friendly stack trace with method names.

Besides that, even if you had source code, it would be useless without symbol file (.pdb), as pdb contains data about mapping between original source code and compiled instructions, as well as other information (symbol names, optimization info, etc).

However, it is not that hard to debug using assembly code if you have a pdb file but not the source code (ok, it is not that easy, either :). These 2 articles (http://www.microsoft.com/msj/0298/hood0298.aspx and http://www.microsoft.com/msj/0698/hood0698.aspx) have enough info to debug most of the usual situations where you might need that.

Comment: Thank you so much Zdeslav, as your explaination and the links provided gives me more clarity on the problem.